# Why is this reference binding ill-formed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

Consider this code:

```
int **p = 0;

class S {
public:
    explicit operator int**&() {
        return p;
    }
};

int main() {
    S a;
    int *const*&b (a); // error in both g++-7 and clang-5.0 with "-std=c++17"
    return 0;
}
```

You will agree

- a qualification conversion from `int**` to `int*const*` is possible, and
- `int *const*&b (a)` is a *direct-initialization*.

First, we refer to 11.6.3, paragraph 5 [dcl.init.ref] from [n4700](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4700.pdf).

> A reference to type “*cv1* `T1 (= int*const*)`” is initialized by an expression of type “*cv2* `T2 (= S)`” as follows:
>
> - If **the reference is an lvalue reference** and the initializer expression
>
>   - ...
>   - **has a class type** (i.e., `T2` is a class type), where `T1` is not reference-related to `T2`, and can be converted to an lvalue of type “*cv3* `T3`”, where “*cv1* `T1`” is reference-compatible with “*cv3* `T3`” (this conversion is selected **by enumerating the applicable conversion functions (16.3.1.6)** and choosing the best one through overload resolution (16.3)),
>
> then **the reference is bound** to the initializer expression lvalue in the first case and **to the lvalue result of the conversion in the second case**...

**Here, we expect `T3` to be `int*const*`.** As noted above, whether it's a possible conversion is determined as per 16.3.1.6, paragraph 1 [over.match.ref].

> ... Assuming that “reference to *cv1* `T`” is the type of the reference being
>   initialized, and “*cv* `S`” is the type of the initializer expression, with `S` a class type, the candidate functions are selected as follows:
>
> - ... For direct-initialization, **those explicit conversion functions** that
>     are not hidden within `S` and yield type “lvalue reference to *cv2* `T2`” or “*cv2* `T2`” or “rvalue reference to *cv2* `T2`”, respectively, where `T2` is the same type as `T` **or can be converted to type `T` with a qualification conversion are also candidate functions**.

**Here, `S::operator int**&` yields "lvalue reference to `T2 (= int**)`", and it can be converted to `T (= int*const*)` by a qualification conversion.** Here, we can say that the conversion is possible, but the program is not accepted in both g++-7 and clang-5.0. Why is that?

Comment: Exactly for the same reason why `int& a = 1;` fails to compile, but I don't know the standard enough to quote any specific paragraph.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Why is that? The conversion yields an lvalue in my case.

Comment: But the lvalue has type of `int**`, but you need `int *const*`, and so a conversion happens.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Do you suggest that a qualification conversion alters a value category? As per 16.3.3.1.1, paragraph 1 [over.ics.scs], `... the Qualification Adjustments do
not change the value category or data representation of the type; ...`

Comment: It depends on the conversion, but yes. `int a = 1; double d = a;`, the `a` is promoted to a prvalue `double`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 That's because of Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, not Qualification Conversion.

Comment: It's integer conversion/promotion, and I don't think it qualifies as Qualification Conversion, because it doesn't involve the top level cv qualifiers, AFAIU. [conv.qual/p1#3](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#1.sentence-3) and [conv.qual/p3](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#3)

Comment: @Rakete1111 I agree that  your case does not involve a qualification conversion. However, I'm pretty sure that the conversion from `int**` to `int*const*` in my case has nothing to do with other standard conversions except a qualification conversion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162043/discussion-between-b1sub-and-rakete1111).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reference initialization rule we're looking for is [[dcl.init.ref]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5):

> A reference to type “*cv1* `T1`” is initialized by an expression of type “*cv2* `T2`” as follows:

We have *cv1* `T1` as `int* const*` and *cv2* `T2` as `S`. We then go through the next sections carefully:

> If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>
> - is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2”, or
> - has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type), where T1 is not reference-related to T2, and can be converted to **an lvalue** of type “cv3 T3”, **where “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv3 T3”** (this conversion is selected by enumerating the applicable conversion functions ([over.match.ref]) and choosing the best one through overload resolution),
>
> then the reference is bound to the initializer expression lvalue in the first case and to the lvalue result of the conversion in the second case (or, in either case, to the appropriate base class subobject of the object).

Our reference is an lvalue reference. The initializer expression is an lvalue but the two types are not [reference-compatible](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#4), so the first bullet does not apply.

The initializer expression does have non-reference-related class type, but it cannot be converted to a reference-compatible type. The reference-compatible part is important. `int**` is **not** reference-compatible with `int* const*`, and while the former can be converted to the latter, the result would not be an lvalue - which is also required.

So, this section doesn't apply, and we [move on](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.2).

> Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type (i.e., cv1 shall be const), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference.

Our reference meets neither of those criteria, so the initialization is ill-formed.

---

A simpler version of this failure would be:

```
int* pi;
int const*& r = pi; // error
```

We can't go through a qualification conversion when we have an lvalue reference to non-const type.

Comment: I supposed that **the second standard conversion sequence of this user-defined conversion sequence** contains only a qualification conversion, so that an lvalue persists. Why is that impossible?

Comment: @b1sub Those kinds of questions are always fundamentally unanswerable to the asker's satisfaction. The direct answer is that qualification conversion is defined in terms of [converting a prvalue](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv#qual-3).

Comment: Your comment suffices. I have overlooked the "prvalue" part as you mentioned.